# About how to build Ubuntu virtual environment using VirtualBox and Vagrant on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, vagrant, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox and Vagrant to build Ubuntu virtual environment on Windows 10.

When I did "vagrant up" with Windows PowerShell, the following error occurred.

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "063b8a06-75ba-46cd-a729-703faf0d4de2", "--type",
>   "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The virtual machine
>   'ubuntu64_default_1491745500976_24277' has terminated unexpectedly
>   during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available
>   in 'C:\Users\(username)\VirtualBox
>   VMs\ubuntu64_default_1491745500976_24277\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component
>   MachineWrap, interface IMachine

I was able to use VirtualBox and Vagrant without problem until a couple of months ago.

However, this time, the above error occurred.

I do not know if it is due to the update around Windows or what is the cause.

Uninstalling VirtualBox and Vagrant and trying on other versions did not solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

This is the detailed log shown in the error sentence.

https://github.com/pekochun/git-study/blob/master/VBoxHardening.log

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the logs the killer blow looks to be:

```
1518.1be0: Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5)
1518.1be0: Error relaunching VirtualBox VM process: 5
```

Now google fu takes me to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=82277 and related posts which suggests this problem might happen after first restart.

Since error `-104` looks like it means `VERR_INVALID_NAME`, I would suggest following those instructions. Beyond that it might be best taking up with virtualbox forums.